# Installing CPAN modules in a specific Perl installation

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have installed Perl in directory "/srv/data203806/MUXmh-Migration/CPAN/localperl/". I have downloaded the tar file and unzipped it. Now how do I install CPAN modules manually to this Perl installation?

Comment: why do you have to do manual installation? Why can't you use the `cpan` or `cpanm` tools? How did you install that perl – the `perlbrew` script helps setting up your environment variables so that you can use multiple perls effectively.

Comment: I don't have access to root directory to install perl. Can I install in any other directory? also CPAN modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are installing a CPAN module as a non-root user then you should use the PREFIX option with Makefile.pl like this:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=<your directory>
make
make install
```

This will install the module in the directory you have specified with the PREFIX option.

Steps to install cpan module:

1. Download the .gz file from cpan website
2. Extract the .gz file
3. Go to the extracted directory
4. Run the following commands

   ```
   perl Makefile.pl PREFIX=<local directory you need>
   make
   make install
   ```

Comment: Thanks Raghu... Can I know how to install using CPAN to particular directory?